# iOS: Multiple Section in TableView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on an app in which I need to show multiple rows with a header. In my case only one section is showing. I have searched everything but can't find a suitable solution.

`Here is my code:`

```
class Timeline: UITableViewCell {
      @IBOutlet weak var timelineData: UITextView!
}

class StudenTimelineViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

let section = ["pizza", "deep dish pizza", "calzone"]

let items = [["Margarita", "BBQ Chicken", "Peproni"], ["sausage", "meat lovers", "veggie lovers"], ["sausage", "chicken pesto", "prawns & mashrooms"]]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return section.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return self.section[section]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineId", for: indexPath) as! Timeline
    let gpsData = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.timelineData.text = gpsData
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

`What I am getting`
[image]

How will I get all the sections. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you're returning height for footer in section not for your header. Did you add your tableView dataSource and delegate? Can you add another screen of how did you implement table view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your method name `func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int` is incorrect and hence not called.

Replace the name with `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` and see the magic happen.

Answer (score 0):

//MARK: - Table view data source

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    let cell: UITableViewCell
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableviewHeader")!

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 32;
}
```